# What is wrong in python-for-android everytime i try to build an apk it always produces a path error

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

I use python-for-android to build an apk and when I try to build a simple apk it always has an error

Everytime I run

```
p4a apk --private /home/espanto/Desktop/AndroidApp --package=org.example.myapp --name "MyApplication" --version 0.1 --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy,numpy
```

it always produces an error that says it can't find the path of my sdkmanager but I already set the path in my bashrc. I can also call android in my terminal without error.

```
    p4a apk --private /home/espanto/Desktop/AndroidApp --package=org.example.myapp --name "MyApplication" --version 0.1 --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy,numpy
[INFO]:    Will compile for the following archs: armeabi
[INFO]:    Android API target was not set manually, using the default of 15
[ERROR]:   Could not find `android` or `sdkmanager` binaries in Android SDK. Exiting.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/p4a", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('python-for-android==0.6.0', 'console_scripts', 'p4a')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 975, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 512, in __init__
    getattr(self, args.subparser_name.replace('-', '_'))(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 144, in wrapper_func
    user_ndk_ver=self.ndk_version)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 238, in prepare_build_environment
    apis = [s for s in targets if re.match(r'^ *API level: ', s)]
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'targets' referenced before assignment
root@espanto-VirtualBox:/home/espanto/Desktop/AndroidApp# p4a apk --private /home/espanto/Desktop/AndroidApp --package=org.example.myapp --name "MyApplication" --version 0.1 --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy,numpy
[INFO]:    Will compile for the following archs: armeabi
[INFO]:    Android API target was not set manually, using the default of 15
[ERROR]:   Could not find `android` or `sdkmanager` binaries in Android SDK. Exiting.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/p4a", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('python-for-android==0.6.0', 'console_scripts', 'p4a')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 975, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 512, in __init__
    getattr(self, args.subparser_name.replace('-', '_'))(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 144, in wrapper_func
    user_ndk_ver=self.ndk_version)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 238, in prepare_build_environment
    apis = [s for s in targets if re.match(r'^ *API level: ', s)]
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'targets' referenced before assignment
root@espanto-VirtualBox:/home/espanto/Desktop/AndroidApp#
```

and this is my .bashrc file

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi

export PATH=$PATH:'/home/espanto/Documents/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools':'/home/espanto/Documents/android-sdk-linux/tools'
export ANDROIDSDK="/home/espanto/Documents/android-sdk-linux"
export ANDROIDNDK="/home/espanto/Documents/android-ndk-r16b"
export ANDROIDAPI="19"
export ANDROIDNDKVER="r16b"
```

Comment: It looks like you've found a bug in p4a (it should exit when it says it will, instead of crashing on the following line), but the real issue seems to be that you haven't passed p4a the location of the Android SDK or NDK. Have you tried to do that some other way?

Comment: I've fixed the actual crashing bug in p4a master, for what it's worth.